# Where did the notion the moon was made of cheese originate?

Tags: folklore, origins

We've all at one point or another heard something about the moon being made of cheese- does anyone know where this myth got started?

Comment: Wallace & Gromit? :) Jokes apart, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_is_made_of_green_cheese) wiki page might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest occurrence I have found of the association between Moon and cheese is in [Aesop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop)'s [fable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables) "The Fox, The Moon, and the River". This is [number 264 in the edition of Laura Gibbs's translations](http://mythfolklore.net/aesopica/oxford/264.htm) (Laura Gibbs, Aesop's Fables: a New Translation Laura Gibbs [Oxford: OUP, 2002]) and has Perry number 669. Aesop lived in the 7th and 6th centuries BCE.

> A fox was out walking one night next to a river. She saw the light of
>   the moon reflected in the water and mistook it for a piece of cheese.
>   The fox started to lap at the water, thinking that if she could drink
>   up all the water, she would find the cheese in the dry riverbed. The
>   fox lapped and lapped at the water until finally she choked and died.
>
> So every greedy man goes chasing after profit with such an intensity
>   that he destroys himself without achieving anything.